# MMa 13, holding previous solutions instead of clearing them

Tags: equation-solving, evaluation, memory

I suspect this is something one line of code will fix, but I have a fairly simple code, that needs to be evaluated at 2 different points. I tried it for the first one... got an answer, it's correct, all good. I tried it for the second, and it just produces the same answer as the first one again. And it's worked that way however many different ways I've written it. Is Mathematica just holding the first solution in memory for some reason?

```
Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{15, 0.906}, {30, 0.457}, {45, 0.309}}

(*Use known data above to make an empirical 1/x model, giving formula*)
f[x] = Fit[data, {1, x^-1}, x] 
(*This gives the model 0.009730769230769204` + 13.441153846153847`/x *)

lineA = 4
lineB = -17
(*select the line wanted*)
x = lineB

f[x]
```

When I enter lineA - I get 3.3700... (correct)

When I change it to lineB - it still produces 3.3700... (incorrect)

Is anyone able to shed light on what I am missing here?

EDIT: Tried closing and re-opening, and now it just returns `f[x]` running the same code, for both lineA and lineB. I am so very confused.

EDIT 2: Response to Lukas' request - here is the full code and outputs haing completely closed and reopened MMa 13:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
(*NEC given data for bending radii on the 2.5MV accelerator switch \
magnet*)
data = {{15, 0.906}, {30, 0.457}, {45, 0.309}}

(*Use to fit a 1/x model to get a general formula for bending radius*)


f[x_] := Fit[data, {1, x^-1}, x]

Out[ ]={{15, 0.906}, {30, 0.457}, {45, 0.309}}
0.009730769230769204` + 13.441153846153847`/x

lineA = 4
lineB = -17
(*select the line wanted*)
x = lineA

(*bending radius (in metres) equals:*)

f[x]
Out[1]=f[x]
```

Sequence of commands: Hitting shift return at the bottom of the code gets `Out[1]=f[x]`. Hitting it at the f[x]=Fit... line and the f[x], gives `Out[13]=0.00973077 + 13.4412/x`. Which I guess is more helpful, but still not the evaluation of that formula when x = -17 (or 4)

Comment: You define lineA as 4, why should it give 3.37??? Then, to define a function you write: f[x_]:= ..  (note the underscore)

Comment: that fit model comes out as =0.0097 + 13.44/x. So when f[4] = 0.0097 + 13.44/4 = 3.37ish.

I changed f[x]=Fit... to f[x_]:=Fit..., but no change resulted

Comment: Please show the exact sequence of commands you enter, starting from a fresh kernel, and include the outputs of the commands below each line (e.g. as `(* 123 *)`. As it stands, I can't reproduce what you are describing.

Comment: `f[x_] = Fit[data, {1, x^-1}, x];` Then `f /@ {4, -17}`

Comment: That one does it. Thank you. If you feel like it, feel free to write it as an answer and i'll mark it as correct for future viewers.